# How do I run a query to split state by zip code?

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 columns, State, zip, and revenue.

```
Select State, SUM(Revenue)
FROM table
group by State
```

I want to split Maryland where zip codes that begin with 216,218, and 219 are East and the rest are west, so the results will be 51 states with a MD east and MD west value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select 
 State,
 CASE WHEN
 -- If it's not MD, then just use the state
    State <> 'MD'
 THEN
    State
 ELSE
    -- It is MD, so work out which sort of MD it is
    CASE WHEN LEFT(Zip,3) IN ('216','218', '219') THEN
        CONCAT(State, ' East')
    ELSE
        CONCAT(State, ' West')
    END
  END, 
  SUM(Revenue)
FROM table
--- Make sure you match grouping for aggregate functions
group by 
    State,
    CASE WHEN LEFT(Zip,3) IN ('216','218', '219') THEN
        CONCAT(State, ' East')
    ELSE
        CONCAT(State, ' West')
    END
```

Comment: It would have taken me longer to type that than it did for you to answer the question, Brilliant thanks!